# open page in new tab asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, response

I am writing a project using ASP.NET C#.

I want to implement linkbutton click event to open new page in a new tab, but before I have to create new session variable. I have tried this:

```
protected void LinkButton_Click3(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string p_id = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
            Session["p_id"] = p_id;
            Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'> window.open('details.aspx','_blank'); </script>");

        }
```

But it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Make sure your popup blocker isnt suppressing the window.

Comment: Does the postback happen? Do you see the script in the generated HTML?

Comment: yes it happens. If I write Response.Redirect("details.aspx"); instead response.write(..); I redirect to details.aspx but in the same window

Comment: This should not be flagged as a duplicate. Just because a few people think you should use response.redirect does not mean it is the same question. This happens all  too often from people thinking they know everything.

Response.Redirect absolutely will not work with my project.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you should disable your popup blocker.

Comment: I have disabled the popup blocker, but the problem is stil occuring

Answer (score 0):

Try this, call this function on button click or document.ready only on page where you want to redirect from.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newTab() 
{
  if (opener.document.getElementById("aspnetForm").target != "_blank") return;   

opener.document.getElementById("aspnetForm").target = "";
opener.document.getElementById("aspnetForm").action = opener.location.href;

}

</script
```

or add this to linkbutton html

```
OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"
```

Comment: ssory, but the problem hasn't solved by using this

Comment: curious, which solution worked from above accepted answer link?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it works for me to just declare whatever I would invoke dynamically from the administrated code into a javascript function and just call it from within with the
RegisterClientScriptBlock method in ClientScript class:

Daclare the window.open function:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function SetRedirect(URI) {
           window.open(URI, "Details", "menubar=no, location=no, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, status=yes, width = 1200, height = 600");
        }
    </script>
```

And from within the code behind class just a gateway caller to this function like:

```
void MessageGateway(string URI)
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
        "logCallBack", @"<script type=""text/javascript"">SetRedirect('" + URI + "');</script>");
}
```

And that's it, you may call this gateway with your stuff as normally you do,

```
MessageGateway(string.Format("../IRMQueryPO.aspx?id={0}", e.Item.Cells[2].Text));
```

You can try tweeking the "target" parameter with "_blank" in order to open a tab instead a window, it's just a matter of the flavor your solution points in.